# React Native bottom tab navigator jumping on initial app load

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm having an issue with bottom tab navigator jumping along with icons on initial app load (Android).
I have Drawer navigator as parent from whom I'm using header and on bottom tab navigator (child) header is hidden.

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
  screenOptions={({navigation, route}) => ({
    headerTitle: '',
    unmountOnBlur: true,
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      borderBottomColor: Color.borderPrimary,
    },
    headerLeft: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeTabNavigator')}>
        <CustomImage
          width={37}
          height={34}
          source={logo}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    headerRight: () => (
      <DrawerToggleButton
        onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
      />
    ),
  })}>
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="HomeTabNavigator"
    component={HomeTabNavigator}
    options={{drawerLabel: 'home'}}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>


--HomeTabNavigator--

<Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({route}) => ({
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarLabel: route.name,
      tabBarIcon: ({color}) => {
        return (
          <CustomImage
            width={25}
            height={25}
            tintColor={color}
            source={filterHomeTabImages(route.name)}
          />
        );
      },
      tabBarStyle: {
        height: 55,
      },
    })}>
```

I tried to wrap my app with SafeAreaProvider with insets all set to 0 and tab navigator with SafeAreaView, but didn't work, also tried to use React-Native-Screens 3.13. as people suggested on git issue and also didn't help. Anyone had same issue and found another solution?

Dependencies:

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "6.5.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.4.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "6.0.13",
"@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.2",
"react-native-screens": "3.17.0",
```

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to describe what you wanna do?

Comment: @michaelBahl Sorry but I can't provide screenshot since it must be a video, problem is that on initial app load, bottom tab navigator icons render outside of bottom tab navigator and then falls down to place where they should be at first place

Comment: Not really a solution , but seems like a "height/position" calculation problem. You can experiment with `requestAnimationFrame(() => {})` method and see if rendering part of the screen with some delay will get the calculation done, avoiding jumping. Then, check if unmountOnBlur or your CustomImage are not causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your

HomeTabNavigator.js

```
<Tab.Navigator>
     .....
</Tab.Navigator>
```

with

```
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

 <SafeAreaProvider> // this is the wraper
       <HomeTabNavigator/>
 </SafeAreaProvider>
```